# Count function is not working properly for sql's result

Tags: php, pdo, count

I wrote code for sign up where I check username , if it is exists in database or not than add new user accordingly. I am new to sql->prepare statement, Problem is in count function , when checking username it works properly, but in else part when adding user it gives me following error

> Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type
> Countable|array, bool

Here is my adduser.php code.

```
<?php 

 include 'config.php';

 //checkusername

 $check = $con->prepare("select username from users where username = ?");
 $check->bindParam(1,$username);
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $check->execute();
 $row = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     if(count($row)){
       echo -1;
  
     }
     
     else{

        $sql = $con->prepare("insert into users(name,username,password) values(?,?,?)");
        $sql->bindParam(1,$name);
        $sql->bindParam(2,$username);
        $sql->bindParam(3,$password);
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $sql->execute();
            echo 1;
     }

 ?>
```

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to use count here, you don't need to know how many fields are in the row. Just check if it's false or not (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php regarding return types)

Comment: Yes, as @ADyson stated and maybe you're getting false with the query so count(false) results in - Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, bool given ...

Comment: Thanks ADyson, you solved my problem once again

Comment: Try counting it like this: `if ($check->rowCount()>0)`. If you get no results, which is false, count() is going to throw an error.

Comment: Don't forget to get rid of md5 and start using password_hash()

Comment: I just removed md5 algorithm from my code and replaced it with password_hash()

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make much sense to use count here, you don't need to know how many fields are in the row.

Just check if it's false or not - see php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php which mentions that `fetch()` will return `false` when it fails (i.e. there is no row available).

This would make more sense:

```
if($row) {
    $sql = $con->prepare("insert into users(name,username,password) values(?,?,?)");
    //...etc...
}
else {
   echo -1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After executing the query with `$check->execute();`, you can use the built-in method to count the returned rows: `$check->rowCount();`.

I think the statement above returned 0 rows, so you can't do `$check->fetch()` and it returns false.

Example:

```php
// Your code here...
$check = $con->prepare("select username from users where username = ?");
$username = $_POST['username']; // This line needs to be before the next one, because you used the variable $username before defining it
$check->bindParam(1,$username);
$check->execute();
if($check->rowCount() > 0) {
  // User does exist
} else {
  // User does not exist
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Edit 2:** I just realised that the answer I've given below is wrong. The thing I suggest instead is checking if there's any value by using the PDO `rowCount()` method, like this: `if ($check->rowCount()>0)`

*wrong stuff below*
You're assigining $username a value after binding it.

```
 $check = $con->prepare("select username from users where username = ?");
 $check->bindParam(1,$username); //bind $username
 $username = $_POST['username']; //assign value
 $check->execute();
```

Try switching those two lines so $username is assigned a value when you're binding it.

```
 $check = $con->prepare("select username from users where username = ?");
 $username = $_POST['username']; //assign value
 $check->bindParam(1,$username); //bind $username   
 $check->execute();
```

**Edit**
In case you're still having issues, try checking if there's any error in the sql statement execution.
After your `$check->execute();` you can add `print_r($check->errorInfo());` to see if your MySQL statement has any issues in it.

Comment: Still getting same error

Comment: @SafinaSiddique I just realised that I was wrong right after I posted it

Comment: anyway, problem is solved just by checking if($row)  and removing count()